# How can I set the time as c# [3 minutes before]

Tags: datetime

System time `12:05:00` `string datetime = "12:15:00"`;

`12:12:00` 3 minutes ago `MessageBox.Show ("3 minutes left");`. How can i do it please give me a suggestion.

How can I update the Windows system clock time.windows.com I want to update the Windows time, but I know I can manually set the date time, but I do not know how to do it from the form

if you have a suggestion please share with me

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to programmatically alter the date/time on your Windows PC? Can you post some C# code from your .NET form showing what you've tried? BTW, `time.windows.com` is the host name of an NTP server provided by Microsoft; not the same thing as your computer's real time clock (Google `NTP` for more info). If Windows on your PC is configured to use NTP to synchronize its the PC clock, you'll need to disable that as a first step. Otherwise, any change you make to your PC clock will only last until Windows synchronizes with `time.windows.com` again.

Comment: Also, the "3 minutes left" and "3 minutes before" in your question suggest that you may be implementing a countdown timer in your form? Are you really trying to adjust your PC's clock, or are you just wanting to display a timer of some kind? Some code would help clear up the confusion.

Comment: Hi Scott, I want to do a neutron-like application I want to update the system clock when I open my projem time should not be wrong error is not accepted the system is a small-scale project together I have to link it to the example below Neutron 10 kb I want to update the system saaat on all conditions project link :https://www.raymond.cc/blog/auto-sync-pc-clock-on-windows-startup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't directly access the CMOS RTC clock under Windows via C#/.NET. In any case, from what I've read, doing so is likely to introduce other problems.

Instead, you might consider programmatically [triggering Windows Internet Time to sync immediately](https://serverfault.com/questions/678472/how-do-you-manually-trigger-the-first-sync-for-internet-time-in-windows), instead of having it wait up to a week for Windows to do it.

- [Another link for doing this](https://serverfault.com/questions/294787/how-do-i-force-sync-the-time-on-windows-workstation-or-server)
- [...and another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772061/windows-api-to-trigger-the-time-synchronization)
- [...and yet another one (may be less helpful)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033838/synchronise-time-c-sharp)
- [finally, here's a Code Project that seems to do something similar to what you want](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18918/Windows-System-Time-Synchronizer)